# Stagger Siblings in Framer Motion to perform Share Buttons Animation?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I have a Share Icon that looks like:

[image: share-icon]

I want the first 5 icons to be shown. The 5th icon being the share icon.

I want the rest of the icons to be under share icon & when someone taps or hovers over it (either tap or hover as I don't know what would be best UX in this case), it should open to the right at their usual positions.

## SocialShare.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { ShareIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid';

import {
  Facebook,
  HackerNews,
  Reddit,
  Twitter,
  LinkedIn,
  Pinterest,
  Telegram,
  Whatsapp,
  Pocket
} from '../icons/index';

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export const SocialShare = ({ title, slug }) => {
  const [share, openShare] = React.useState(false);
  const [host, setHost] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHost(window.location.host);
  }, []);

  const url = `${isProduction ? 'https://' : 'http://'}${host}/${slug}`;
  const text = title + url;
  const via = 'deadcoder0904';
  const sharer = {
    facebook: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${url}`,
    twitter: `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${url}&text=${text}&via=${via}`,
    reddit: `https://www.reddit.com/submit?title=${title}&url=${url}`,
    hackernews: `https://news.ycombinator.com/submitlink?u=${url}&t=${title}`,
    linkedin: `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=${url}`,
    pinterest: `https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=${url}&description=${title}`,
    telegram: `https://telegram.me/share/url?url=${url}&text=${text}`,
    whatsapp: `https://wa.me/?text=${title}%0D%0A${url}%0D%0A%0D%0A${text}`,
    pocket: `https://getpocket.com/edit.php?url=${url}`
  };

  const variants = {
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      translateX: -16
    },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      translateX: 0
    }
  };

  return (
    <ul className="flex items-center mt-8 space-x-4">
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.facebook} title="Share on Facebook">
          <Facebook />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.twitter} title="Share on Twitter">
          <Twitter />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.reddit} title="Share on Reddit">
          <Reddit />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.hackernews} title="Share on Hacker News">
          <HackerNews />
        </a>
      </li>
      <motion.li className="cursor-pointer" whileHover={{}}>
        <ShareIcon
          className="w-6 h-6 text-gray-300"
          onClick={() => {
            openShare(!share);
          }}
        />
      </motion.li>

      <motion.li
        className=""
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
        variants={variants}
        transition={{
          type: 'tween',
          ease: 'easeInOut'
        }}
      >
        <a className="" href={sharer.linkedin} title="Share on LinkedIn">
          <LinkedIn />
        </a>
      </motion.li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.pinterest} title="Share on Pinterest">
          <Pinterest />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.telegram} title="Share on Telegram">
          <Telegram />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.whatsapp} title="Share on Whatsapp">
          <Whatsapp />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a className="" href={sharer.pocket} title="Share on Pocket">
          <Pocket />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

The icons are in a `flex` container so I can't use `staggerChildren`. Stagger Children is exactly what I'm looking for but I can't find a solution to this using Flexbox?

Do I need to change the DOM elements by adding a wrapper? But that would break the `ul>li` combo.

All I want is it all the icons open when I hover on share to the right & when I stop hovering, they come back under share icon & disappear. Basically, share icon functionality like https://codepen.io/romswellparian/full/mJXdqV:

[image: animated share gif]

It only should be to the right & first 4 icons should be always shown.

I've made a complete Stackblitz reproduction → https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-animation-framer-motion?file=components%2FSocialShare.jsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Stagger Children

Flexbox shouldn't prevent you from using `staggerChildren`.

To use `staggerChildren` you add it to the `transition` property of the parent variants. That means the parent of your list items needs to be a motion component, as do the list items you want to animate.

```
const listVariants = {
  hidden: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1,
      staggerDirection: -1
    }
  },
  visible: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.1
    }
  }
};

const itemVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: -16
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0
  }
};

return (
    <motion.ul
      variants={listVariants}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={share ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
    >
      <motion.li variants={itemVariants}>
        <a href={sharer.linkedin} title="Share on LinkedIn">
          <LinkedIn />
        </a>
      </motion.li>
      {/* ...etc */}
    </motion.ul>
);
```

Here's a quick fork of your project that does what you're describing:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-animation-framer-motion-e5fp5p?file=components/SocialShare.jsx

### Animate Presence

If you actually want to remove the items from the DOM when they are hidden, then you need to use [AnimatePresence](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/). This requires that you wrap all the items what will enter and exit the DOM in the `<AnimatePresence>` tag. Each item will need an `initial`, `animate` and `exit` variant that describes the animation, and **each item needs a unique key**. The last one is easy to forget.

Unfortunately, I don't think StaggerChildren works with AnimatePresence in the way you want it to. To stagger the enter and exit animations you can use [Dynamic Variants](https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##dynamic-variants) with a custom prop to define the animation delay for each item.

Short example:

```
const itemVariants = {
  hidden: i => ({
    opacity: 0,
    x: -16,
    transition: {
      delay: i * 0.1
    }
  }),
  visible: i => ({
    opacity: 1,
    x: 0,
    transition: {
      delay: i * 0.1 // custom prop used to stagger delay
    }
  })
};

return (
  <ul className="flex items-center mt-8 space-x-4">
    <AnimatePresence>
      {share && (<>
        <motion.li
          variants={itemVariants}
          key="linkedin"    /* don't forget key! */
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          exit="hidden"
          custom={1}  /* custom prop used to stagger delay */
        >
          <a href={sharer.linkedin} title="Share on LinkedIn">
            <LinkedIn />
          </a>
        </motion.li>

        <motion.li
          variants={itemVariants}
          key="pinterest"
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
          exit="hidden"
          custom={2}
        >
          <a href={sharer.pinterest} title="Share on Pinterest">
            <Pinterest />
          </a>
        </motion.li>
        {/* etc... */}
      </>)}
    </AnimatePresence>
  </ul>
)
```

Here's the StackBlitz with AnimatePresence:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-animation-framer-motion-wjdxhc?file=components/SocialShare.jsx

The way your example is set up, removing elements from the `<ul>` container causes it to shift (since the container size changes). I fixed that by setting an explicit width, but you could also change the flex alignment of float it or whatever is going to work with your actual project.

Comment: This is beautiful & exactly what I wanted, thank you. Looks so simple :)

Comment: check my recent edit. it makes sure that i cant click on the icons when they're hidden but it also removes the hide animation. any ideas on how to fix the hide animation but still make sure i cant click on hidden items?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to edit the accepted answer with code that doesn't work... I updated the answer with an example for how to use AnimatePresence to animate elements that are removed from the DOM, which seemed like what you were trying to do in your edit.

Comment: naah, it was a working example when i put it but then i realised exit animations don't work. i think 1st example was easier. this one is unnecessarily complex for such a simple thing. isn't there any way to make this any simpler? i mean i exactly want `staggerChildren` to work but both with `initial` & `animate` working. i don't need it to remove elements from DOM, just that there isn't a clickable link on hover when the share icon isn't visible. is there a way?

Comment: You could still use `staggerChildren` if you add and remove the **parent** element (not the children) with `AnimatePresence` and `afterChildren`. But that would require that you have a separate `ul` or other container just for the animating items, which your question said was something you wanted to avoid.

Comment: thank you so much. I think I got it. I need separate `ul` to make it simple which is what I was trying to do earlier haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Cadin answer I've found you can use both `staggerChildren` and `AnimatePresense` to provide a smoother animation when rendering lists.

```
const staggerChildrenVariant = {
  animate: {
    transition: {
      staggerChildren: 0.5,
    },
  }
};

const childVariant = {
 hidden: { height: 0 },
 visible: { height: 'auto' }
};

<motion.div variants={staggerChildrenVariant} initial="animate" animate="animate">
  <AnimatePresence>
    {arr.map((arrItem) => (
      <motion.div
        key={arrItem.id}
        variants={childVariant}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
        exit="hidden"
      >
        ...
      </motion.div>
    ))}
  </AnimatePresence>
</motion.div>
```